# Pass-through heterogeneous (non-uniform) JSON column in Spark

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

We are processing data with Apache Spark 3.1.x where one field contains fully free-form JSON, so the individual records can contain same keys, but with different datatypes (`payload.field1` in this example can be string, boolean or number):

```json
{"timestamp": "2021-07-30T09:41:51Z", "payload": {"field1": "some text"}}
{"timestamp": "2021-07-30T09:41:52Z", "payload": {"field1": true}}
{"timestamp": "2021-07-30T09:41:53Z", "payload": {"field1": 123}}
```

Our goal is to keep `payload` field intact. When we let Spark autodetect the schema:

```java
 Dataset<Row> events = spark.read().json("file:////users/user/input.json");

 // some processing is going on here

 events.write().json("file:///users/user/output.json");
```

Output is as following (notice `payload.field` now being a string):

```json
{"payload":{"field1":"some text"},"timestamp":"2021-07-30T09:41:51Z"}
{"payload":{"field1":"true"},"timestamp":"2021-07-30T09:41:51Z"}
{"payload":{"field1":"123"},"timestamp":"2021-07-30T09:41:52Z"}
```

Spark's `printSchema()` output:

```
root
 |-- payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

The best workaround we came up so far is this:

```java
Dataset<String> eventsAsString = spark.read().text("file:////users/user/input.json").as(Encoders.STRING());

Dataset<Row> events2 = eventsAsString.select( //
        get_json_object(col("value"), "$.timestamp").alias("timestamp"), //
        get_json_object(col("value"), "$.payload").alias("payload") // This will keep payload as string for Spark
);

// Do some processing of events here

// We have to write JSON as string to prevent Spark from encoding payload's field JSON:
events2.withColumn("joined", concat( //
        format_string("{\"timestamp\":\"%s\", ", col("timestamp")), //
        format_string("\"payload\":%s}", col("payload")) //
)).select(col("joined")).write().text("file:///users/user/output.txt");
```

Output we get is what we want, datatypes are unchanged:

```json
{"timestamp":"2021-07-30T09:41:51Z", "payload":{"field1":"some text"}}
{"timestamp":"2021-07-30T09:41:52Z", "payload":{"field1":true}}
{"timestamp":"2021-07-30T09:41:53Z", "payload":{"field1":123}}
```

The solution above works but feels super hacky. Maybe we are missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For read, we can specific the schema before read.
For write, I don't come up with better idea.

```
    val schema = StructType(Array[StructField](
      StructField("timestamp", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty),
      StructField("payload", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty)) // force string type
    )

    val df: Dataset[Row] = spark.read.schema(schema).json(ds)

    df.map(r => "{\"timestamp\": \"%s\", \"payload\": %s".format(r.getString(0), r.getString(1)))
      .write.text("xxx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to work without `Metadata.empty` as well.